# Error: This socket has been ended by the other party

Tags: node.js

Am deploying one node js project in a linux evniroment everything is going fine ,but after 12 to 24 hours its throwing this error and app is not working ??

```
    Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
        at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:275:12)
        at Protocol.<anonymous> (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:69:27)
        at Protocol.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at Protocol._emitPacket (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:208:8)
        at Query.<anonymous> (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:121:12)
        at Query.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at Query.start (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:29:8)
        at Protocol._startSequence (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:262:14)
        at Protocol._enqueue (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:134:10)
        at Connection.query (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:165:25)
        --------------------
        at Protocol._enqueue (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:48)
        at Connection.query (/opt/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:165:25)
        at Object.query (/opt/node/api/database.js:78:16)
        at Object.Wait.applyAndWait (/opt/node/node_modules/wait.for/waitfor.js:45:12)
         at Object.Wait [as for] (/opt/node/node_modules/wait.for/waitfor.js:61:21)
        at exports.getStories (/opt/node/api/stories.js:37:23)
        at /opt/node/node_modules/wait.for/waitfor.js:15:31
    Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
        at new View (/opt/node/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:41:42)
        at Function.app.render (/opt/node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:486:12)
        at ServerResponse.res.render (/opt/node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
        at Object.errorHandler [as handle] (/opt/node/app.js:29:7)
        at next (/opt/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:188:17)
        at Object.clientErrorHandler [as handle] (/opt/node/app.js:23:5)
        at next (/opt/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:188:17)
        at Object.logErrors [as handle] (/opt/node/app.js:16:3)
        at next (/opt/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:188:17)
        at next (/opt/node/node_modules/e

xpress/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:11
```

Dont know where I am wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your relevant code?

Comment: its a very big project which part i need to show u???

Comment: I don't know your project, neither does anyone here. This guide is very good and should help you post the relevant code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is an issue with the underlying mysql driver. I'm also looking for solutions.